# convergence of $\sum (1-1/\log(n^a))^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which $a\in \mathbb R\setminus  \{0\}$ does  $\sum_{n\geq2} \left(1-\frac{1}{\log(n^a)}\right)^n$ converge? Is it possible to apply the comparison test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that, since as $x\to 0,\, \log (1-x)\le -x$

$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{\log(n^a)}\right)^n=e^{n\log\left(1-\frac{1}{\log(n^a)}\right)}\le e^{-\frac{n}{\log(n^a)}}=\frac1{e^{a\frac{n}{\log(n)}}}$$

therefore for $a >0$ the given series converge by limit comparison test, for example with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$ and for $a<0$ diverges.

Indeed for $a>0$

$$\frac{\frac1{e^{a\frac{n}{\log(n)}}}}{\frac1{n^2}}=\frac{n^2}{e^{a\frac{n}{\log(n)}}} \to 0$$

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me. I have just joined this plataform. I'm trying to understand the similarity that you put. Can you give me any clue? Thanks!

Comment: @MarcCasalsSalvador It is the asymptotic notation, that is for $n$ large the term of the series behaves like $e^{-\frac{n}{\log(n^a)}}$. It is a way to see in few steps how things are going on, then we need to formalize the idea by a formal proof. I'll add something on that to better explain. in this particular case we have used that for $x \to 0$ we have $\log (1+x)\sim x$ or more precisely $\log (1+x)=x+o(x)$.

Comment: @MarcCasalsSalvador I've added a simpler observation by the inequality which show that the series converges by direct comparison test with $\sum e^{-\frac{n}{\log(n^a)}}$.